# Why useState does not replace old value?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I noticed if I re-render a component with a new value that is used as initializer for useState, the value returned is cached from previous render instead of replacing it with new value. How can I avoid that behavior?

Minimal example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Test />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));

function Test() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState();
  setTimeout(() => {
    setVal(5);
  }, 1000);
  return <Cached value={val}></Cached>;
}

function Cached({ value }) {
  console.log({ value });
  const [val] = useState(value || "cached");
  console.log({ val });
  return <p>{val}</p>;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-1ykk3?file=/index.js

If you check console, `value` and `val` have different values and I would expect them to be the same. But UI only prints `"cached"`

Comment: Why are you using useState without declaring setVal in your cached component? Its basically just an instance variable at that point

Comment: this is a minimal example, I'm using setVal in a production environment where this bug appeared

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because when you're initializing your state:

```
const [val] = useState(value || "cached");
```

`value` is undefined. That's because it's being set in the timeout in the parent component. Since the child component renders before the timeout completes and `value` gets updated to 5, it stays as "cached" (this is because `useState` will only initialize once). In order to update the state to reflect the props being passed down, you'd need to use a `useEffect` hook with value as the dependency. That way you can update the state to reflect the change in props.

```
function Cached({ value }) {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(value ? value : "cached");
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setVal(value);
  }, [value]);

  return <p>{val}</p>; // will update to 5 once prop changes
}
```

Comment: "this is because useState will only initialize once" Thanks that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

useState set value only once when the components renders firstly.
so it won't be updated when the props changes.

So you can put props value on the render html of Cached component directly

```
function Cached({ value }) {

   return <p>{value}</p>;
}
```

or you can use useEffect hook and pass value in it as a dependency

```
function Cached({ value }) {
   const [val, setVal] = useState(value || "cached");

   useEffect(()=>{
      setVal(value)
   },[value])

   return <p>{val}</p>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work perfectly fine there is just one issue

```
function Cached({ value }) {
  console.log({ value });
  const [val] = useState(value || "cached");
  console.log({ val });
  return <p>{val}</p>;
}
```

here you are passing value from props to useState which is the reason for this issue

now you can do two things

either

```
function Cached({ value }) {
  console.log({ value });
  const [val] = useState(value || "cached");

  useEffect(() => {
    setVal(value);
  }, [value]);

  console.log({ val });
  return <p>{val}</p>;
}
```

here we are just updating the state whenever the prop "value" changes, using useEffect

or directly use the value from props

```
function Cached({ value }) {
  return <p>{value}</p>;
}
```